# How to get x and y distance from a csv file in a 3d plot?

Tags: r

I am very new to R so it could be that this is a very easy question.
I have measurements over an area (x,y) and I want to plot the location and intensity of the signal as a 3d graph.

The files I get have information like this.

```
;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
1;1;2;8;2;0;0;0;0
2;2;4;16;4;2;0;0;0
3;4;16;32;16;4;2;0;0
4;2;4;16;4;2;0;0;0
5;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
6;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
7;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
8;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0
```

The first row and col specify the location and then the values for each location in the matrix. I load the csv file with
`test5 <- read.csv("~/test4.csv", header= TRUE , row.names = 1, sep = ";")`
then change it to a matrix so it can be plotted. 
`test5 <- as.matrix(test5)`

In r the information looks like this:

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8
1  1  2  8  2  0  0  0  0
2  2  4 16  4  2  0  0  0
3  4 16 32 16  4  2  0  0
4  2  4 16  4  2  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

So my header is not the distance values that I orignaly had and when i plot using
persp3d(test5)

I get a graph but the x and y is always 0-1 and not 1-8 (or something else depending on what the file says). What am i doing wrong?
Thankful for any advice.

Question updated for clarity

Comment: added more info in the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for your problem.

```
test5 <- read.table(text='
    0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8
0.1 1   2   8   2   0   0   0   0
0.2 2   4   16  4   2   0   0   0
0.3 4   16  32  16  4   2   0   0
0.4 2   4   16  4   2   0   0   0
0.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.6 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.7 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.8 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
', header=T)
test5 <- as.matrix(test5)


library(rgl)
persp3d(x=seq(0.1,0.8,0.1),
        y=seq(0.1,0.8,0.1),
        xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z",
        z=test5, color=terrain.colors(32))
```

[image]